# kobuki_mgs missing

Tags: ros, intel, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wanted to use the "IntelROSProject" and followed the guidelines.
But upon running the command "catkin_make", I got an error saying that cmake failed.
Reason was that he was missing kobuki_msgs, but the github page for the package that depends on it ([ros_moving_object](https://github.com/intel/ros_moving_object)) says that it should be part of the full desktop install.

And in fact, I could find the kobuki_msgs...
Why aren't they part anymore of the full desktop install?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289132/kobuki_mgs-missing/) by [AlexChris003](https://answers.ros.org/users/33847/alexchris003/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> And in fact, I could find the kobuki_msgs... Why aren't they part anymore of the full desktop install?

`kobuki_msgs` has never been part of any of the official ROS metapackages (neither any of the other `kobuki_*` packages). See [REP-142](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0142.html).

---

From [your issue](https://github.com/intel/ros_moving_object/issues/2) on the `ros_moving_object` tracker I gather that you've cloned the `kobuki_msgs` from source and added them to your workspace.

I would recommend you follow the workflow shown in #q252478 whenever you try to build something from sources in ROS. `rosdep` is the tool that installs dependencies of packages for you, and in this case would have installed the binary [kobuki_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/kobuki_msgs) package for you, as it is actually released for ROS Kinetic.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexChris003](https://answers.ros.org/users/33847/alexchris003/) on 2018-04-20**:
Oh, okay, my bad. Thanks for your hint!
But the way they listeted the needed packages, it seemed to me kobuki is also part of the full install...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-20**:
I don't know why the readme makes it appear that `kobuki_msgs` is part of `desktop_full`. That would be something to ask Intel.